# db_reader user with Exec rights on sp which contains INSERT & TRUNCATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

User with db_reader would like to get execute permission on stored procedure that contains INSERT and TRUNCATE statements against existing tables.

Just to see I granted what was requested, but it seems like it doesn't work.
Is such mix of permissions doable?

EDIT: I granted permissions on sp using this:

```
use [dbName]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[spFront_ProcedureName] TO [ABC\serviceAccount]
GO
```

Comment: Huh? `db_reader` simply grants a `USER` the ability to `SELECT` from any objects in the database, unless they have an explicit `DENY`. A `USER` with the `db_reader` role cannot execute a stored procedure on the database, as they do not have the `EXECUTE` permission.

Comment: If you gave them permission to `EXECUTE` said stored procedure, and then the other objects (which you perform the `INSERT` and `TRUCNATE` on) are in the same database and owned by the same `USER`, then they would, however, be able to execute the SP and the `INSERT`/`TRUNCATE` would work, as the permissions would be inherited via ownership chaining. If this isn't working, however, then [edit] yoru question and show us the SQL you ran to give them the permissions you gave them and include the error message they receive.

Comment: You can give execution rights on the stored procedure and it could work if it contains a EXECUTE AS OWNER clause. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Larnu - I granted rights as per sql in edit. This user however is not owner of any of these objects.

Comment: The `USER` doesn't need to be the owner of the objects, the objects just need the same owner. You haven't included the error though.

Answer (score 0):

Granting EXECUTE permission on the Stored Procedure allows the user to call the procedure.

However, depending upon what the procedure does, it may still not do as you expect. Specifically around TRUNCATE, see the info at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) which identifies that additional permission may be needed to use TRUNCATE unless the procedure is carefully crafted.

The specific error message may help identify whether the issue arises from this or if it is from ownership chaining.